# Accessing the PowerPoint XML using python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

How the access the attributes persent in xml files of path ppt/slides/ and ppt/slides/_rels.

1. I want to access the **Relationship** tag in ppt/slides/_rels/slide1.xml
2. I want to access the **a:graphicData** and **p:spPr** tags in ppt/slides/slide1.xml

Comment: Explain what you're trying to accomplish by accessing those so we have some notion of what approach might suit you. If all you want to do is access these you can unzip the .pptx and read the XML files in the package.

Comment: @scanny I need to find the display dimension of image not the actual dimension of the image

Comment: What about `shape.width` and `shape.height` on the picture shape?